# android : get reference to gridview inside a relative layout

Tags: android, gridview, android-relativelayout

I have this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/online_top_deals_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="none" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button1" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/topWebsitesGrid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:columnWidth="150dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try obtaining a reference to grid view

```
View topWebsitesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_online_top_websites, container, false);

        mTopWebsitesGrid = (GridView) topWebsitesView.findViewById(R.id.topWebsitesGrid);
```

I get ClassCastException error "Relativelayout cannot be cast to gridview"

Comment: At first glance what you're doing looks right. Have you tried cleaning the project? It's a common problem and cleaning the project helps.

Comment: Most likely cleaning the project fixes resource references

Comment: yup, did the work. Thanks :)

Comment: Height of Relative layout is wrap_content and Gridview has fill_parent???

Answer (score 1):

As per your code I think there is no problem. I think R.java class does not build up automatically . Sometimes it happens. First clean the project and run if you get any error then please let me inform.

Thanks!!!